# How to prioritize social media links in showShareSheet feature of Branch.io?

Tags: branch.io

On **BranchUniversalObj.showShareSheet**, it shows up facebook link on the top, can we reorganize it to Whatsapp?

[image: BranchUniversalObj.showShareSheet Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex with Branch.io here:

You sure can! When you're configuring your `ShareSheetStyle` object, just set `WHATS_APP` as the preferred sharing option, like so:

```
ShareSheetStyle shareSheetStyle = new ShareSheetStyle(MainActivity.this, "My Sharing Message Title", "My Sharing message body")
        .setCopyUrlStyle(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send), "Save this URl", "Link added to clipboard")
        .setMoreOptionStyle(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search), "Show more")
        .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.WHATS_APP);
```

That will put WhatsApp at the top of the list, if it is installed on the device.

Comment: I am using Cordova/Ionic. can you help with this? @Alex Bauer

Comment: @SandeshBSuvarna this is not a method we surface in the Cordova SDK. I'm not really fluent on the Cordova/Ionic platform, but I believe it should work if you customize the underlying SDK. Take a look at [this section](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/blob/6ce246fe880ddc4ec2417768fc8a2d3ec1941f09/src/android/io/branch/BranchSDK.java#L411-L418) and let me know how it goes!